# Fragments and progress update dialogues

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i have a tabhost with a fragment. One of the functions of the fragment is to download a file when a button is clicked.

I wrote all the code as its own Activity initially so i know it all works. I am now trying to migrate it into a fragment to be used with the tab host as i discussed the problem I am having is with the progress update dialogue for the file download.

I am using the following code:

```
 //------------progress updater
@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file...");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            return progressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

When i call showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
 or dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

they now return the error "cannot resolve method"

I am relatively new to android programming so i am sure its something simple i have missed. I would appreciate any help anyone is willing to provide on this topic.

Comment: what is the code of `showDialog`, is it a function that you defined?

Comment: show the stack treace and relevant code please

Comment: they are both defined in the Activity class. that is why they are useable when the code was in an activity like i said now that its in a fragment i am not sure how to handle it